# What is this "F" subscript symbol that shows up in this loss function?

Tags: loss-function, distance

i was reading this https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.14535v1.pdf paper when i came across this: [image]

What is this F? Initially i assumed this was a standard L2 distance but i'm not so sure anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The subscript F is used to denote the Frobenius norm, see also the section on the Frobenius norm on [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) to see an example of the notation (including one with a superscript 2 as is the cass for the loss function shown).